How should I tell my manager that he could delay my retirement with a raise?
What's a good way to tell my manager that the timing of my upcoming retirement will depend partly on how big my next raise is, without giving him the feeling that I'm extorting him or giving him an ultimatum?
I'm planning to retire in the spring of 2026 at the latest, or as soon as I find I'm not enjoying the job anymore or can no longer resist the siren song of retirement. The more they pay me, the more of that time span I'd be likely to stay. I haven't told this to anyone at work.
I'm not worried about getting targeted for termination, as I'd probably get a severance and would happily take the money and run. I may well get laid off anyway, since the product I'm working on is not selling well, our team has had other layoffs recently, and I'm probably next in line. However, he seems happy with my work and would probably prefer to keep me on if the budget allows.
I know the company deserves no loyalty from me because it has none for me, but I respect my manager and I don't want this conversation to feel antagonistic to either of us. So the challenge is how to present it as an opportunity for him to keep me on longer, instead of a threat to leave if I don't get what I want.

Does your manager know your retirement is about to come? If they do, then they could approach you to talk about plans. That would make it easier for you. 2026 isn't tomorrow so this could take a while. Did you talk about retirement at all, although not mentioning you would be willing to stay longer? Perhaps you want to delay your decision a bit as you are "not enjoying the job anymore", so who knows how you think about this next year. Also, if you apparently don't need the money, you could want to think about working less for less money instead of working the same time for more money.

Is partial retirement an option for you? You could arrange for say, I plan to work 50% for (extended date), but only for amount X, which is larger than 50%?

"without giving him the feeling that I'm extorting him" -- Since that's exactly what you're doing, it seems hard to avoid.

@Barmar seems a bit odd to call it extortion--you'd have to call basically every instance of asking for a raise extortion as well. This isn't "or I'll quit right before the deadline and leave you in a lurch", it's "I'm probably retiring within the next few years".

@Kaia It's either extortion or an ultimatum, and the OP didn't want to look like either.

@Barmar Yeah, my issue is specifically with "extortion", the overall sentiment of "you are giving an ultimatum, you can only soften that so much" is I think fine. (An ultimatum has its place in clear, respectful communication; I don't think the same can be said for extortion)

@Kaia Yes, I was too flippant. But the OP themselves thought it could be viewed that way.

I would suggest approaching your manager to talk about your long term plans. Let them know that you feel you're in your last two years of employment. You might mention that this frees up some training budget to use on others, or that you'd rather not be put on a 5 year project you won't get to see the end of. At the same time, you can assure them you're not about to give "two weeks notice" of retiring and that you'd like it to be a smooth and well planned transition.
If your boss seems amenable to the conversation, and is asking things like how firm your date is, you can say, straight up, "if my upcoming review includes a raise of at least x, I'll stay at least 18 months after that. If it's less, that's my sign that I'm not as valued as I thought I was and I will start to consider an earlier departure."
Yes, the boss might say "I don't like uncertainty, and I'd rather use the raises on the folks who are staying. How about we start planning for 3 months from now?" It's not clear you would consider that a bad outcome. And they might say "I appreciate your open-ness. Since we only have to pay you that much for 18 months, it's actually a little more doable. Let me see what I can arrange." Which way will it go? You know your boss, and your company, better than we do. But I don't see much of a downside if you don't mind "how about you just retire right now?" as an outcome of the conversation.
If the boss seems stiff and uncomfortable, isn't asking questions, isn't smiling, and even is trying to change the subject, say something like "I wanted to give you some insight into my thoughts. I'll let you know when my timeline gets firmer, if you like." And then drop it, and make your decisions without giving the boss any more opportunities to know what would influence them.

I don't know which country is being talked about, but "How about you just retire right now?" lays a very good foundation for a constructive dismissal suit in the UK.

@AndrewLeach: Won't fly, I expect. In times of downsizing, offering early retirement is perfectly reasonable.

If they're offering early retirement (which involves some sort of enhancement) that's reasonable, yes.

What is the upside of providing OP's manager with parameters "a raise of at least x, ...18 months" as opposed to making this the start of a collective decision, along the lines: "I have to weight the perks some extra money will provide against the free time i'll get to enjoy sooner. "

saying you want "a substantial raise" without a number opens the possibility of the boss working quite hard to get you x/2 and you saying that's not good enough. Unpleasant for everyone. If you think the boss would enjoy an exploratory conversation to find the number, ok, but the answers and comments all over this question are full of people who do not believe that 5% or 10% could actually influence a decision to retire, and the boss is quite likely to be the same. In that context, the more information OP provides, the more likely they will get what they want.

I wouldn't cast it as "I'm not as valuable as I thought", and more of "I do still enjoy it here, and that would change the math for us in a way where it would make more sense to stay longer." I know at least in the US, your SS payments for your entire retirement is based on something like your last 5 years of income, so a couple extra years at a higher income can make a huge lifetime difference. This is normal retirement planning stuff, and there should be no shame in talking about it. Maybe get real numbers about this from a retirement planner first, so you can get as specific as you like.

@T.E.D. this is a really important bargaining point.

@T.E.D. I don't think this is accurate "in the US, your SS payments for your entire retirement is based on something like your last 5 years of income"  That sounds correct for many union/pension based benefits, but I believe Social Security is based on calculations across all (or most) of you r working career.

@cdkMoose - I looked it up. Its actually 35 years. Not sure how I got it in my head it was as small as 5, but still If you work more than 35 years before retirement, every year you work after that likely replaces an early low-earning year with a later high-earning one for the purposes of your future benefit calculation.  It looks like they do index for inflation though, so its probably a bigger deal if those early years had significantly less hours or a cheaper career.

@T.E.D.: Or if those early years were in an entry-level position that you've been promoted out of (with a substantial raise, of course).

@Kevin - Yes, although I'd advise a person to check. I was surprised to discover that my salary as a straight-out-of-college software developer back in the early 1990's, when adjusted for inflation, is about the same money I'm making now as a senior developer at the top of my company's pay scale. (I am living in a significantly cheaper place now, but as far as Social Security is concerned its the same money if they use the same inflation adjustment)

@T.E.D., the average American worker hasn't had a real-terms payrise since around the time when Armstrong was going to the moon.

@Steve - Technically I could argue its a pay cut, since fresh-from-college new hires are presumably making a fair bit less. I remember watching a SuperFriends episode back in the 1970's where new computers allowed so nobody had to work any more (and the problems that caused). How naïve in retrospect those writers were, to think that companies buying computers would pass the efficiency gains of computerization on to workers, rather than just enriching themselves and their shareholders with them.

@T.E.D., in your personal career it almost certainly is a pay cut, once you adjust the wage for your age and experience.

@Steve - Yup. The much lower cost of living here muddies things a bit. I could probably do half again (or more) better in a coastal city or some "hot" place like Austin, if I didn't mind buying a tiny house for $1mil.  But for the government's purposes they don't care about that.


What's a good way to tell my manager that the timing of my upcoming retirement will depend partly on how big my next raise is, without giving him the feeling that I'm extorting him or giving him an ultimatum?

Being in a financial position to retire (as well as what it implies about your age) generally means that financial pressures have receded and small variations in income become immaterial to major decisions like whether to continue working at all or not.
So unless the raise being considered is an extremely large (and for the employer, a desperate) one, then it might not ring true that your behaviour will be significantly influenced by the raise.
You also say that the decision will only be "partly" influenced by the raise.
To me, it either sounds like a bluff from someone who fully intends to continue working, or it sounds like a non-serious conversation from someone whose dedication or compulsion to work is no longer there, and from that position of security is now chancing his hand on an ego-boosting raise but will ultimately choose to retire for other reasons and will be difficult to retain.

I may well get laid off anyway, since the product I'm working on is not selling well, our team has had other layoffs recently, and I'm probably next in line.

So why would they want to pay anything exceptional to keep you?

So the challenge is how to present it as an opportunity for him to keep me on longer, instead of a threat to leave if I don't get what I want.

What you would have to explain is why the situation is not essentially about you threatening to retire sooner if you aren't given an influential raise! You would have to articulate why your motives are not as bald as that.
You would also have to explain why the prospect of your retiring sooner is something the company would exceptionally wish to avoid even if it only briefly delays the inevitable.
Retirements happen all the time (as do sudden deaths and sickness from older workers) and the disruption will normally be priced in by the employer already.
The employer would also want to avoid every near-retired worker from lodging demands for extreme increases because they think they'll get one, and then the worker retiring prematurely when refusal offends them and they feel obliged to carry through the threat they'd used to reinforce their demand.
So unless you are in a bargaining situation which your colleagues can see is very different from their own, and which your employer knows your colleagues can see is different, they may refuse a raise on principle because it's easier to suffer your loss now than to soon face a chorus of similar demands from your colleagues who would be emboldened by your success.

And the moment you tell them you’re going to retire soon, they’re going to start mitigating that risk. They’re NOT going to pay you more to keep you on and thus increase that risk.

@bob, I assume if he is of a normal retirement age, then saying he's going to retire roughly in the next couple of years isn't really news to the employer. I don't myself see how paying him more to prevent the retirement from occuring, "thus increases the risk" of retirement. I think what you're describing is that there are lots of older workers (not all) on the verge of retirement who the employer already wants to get rid of (not retain with pay rises), and so creating any kind of retention dilemma for them will simply prompt them to assume you are going or select you next for redundancy.

True I just meant that saying “I’m not staying more than 2 years” solidifies for them what they may have already guessed and just speeds up the “replace them” machinery that was likely already in motion. That machinery is about minimizing risk to the company from a messy transition when OP leaves. There’s no benefit to OP by announcing “I’m leaving in 2 years, maybe less if you pay me more” b/c they’ll only hear “I’m leaving in 2 years” and immediately start the off boarding planning and OP will benefit exactly zero. That’s what I meant.

They’re not going to try to retain OP b/c that just puts them back into “I’m not sure when OP is leaving but it could be any time” territory which is higher risk than “I know OP is leaving in 2 years” territory, or even “I’ll push OP out in 2 months territory”. That’s what I meant about them not keeping OP and thus increasing their risk.

I question your motivation on a raise.

or as soon as I find I'm not enjoying the job anymore or can no longer resist the siren song of retirement

None of that has to do with money.  What difference would a large raise really make?  Is there a pension involved that is based on your last salary?  Most companies don't do that so some clarification could help.
You don't mention a country or location but most of us, these days in the US, received little or no pension and are dependent upon our retirement account balances.  A raise, in your waning years of work, will not make much of a difference.  Most of us need to rely on compound interest to build a sufficient balance.
So perhaps you need to have a more honest conversation with yourself.  Why will a raise motivate you into staying?  How long will that motivation last?  Probably not long.
I would suggest a different course of action:  asked to be moved to part-time.  This way you can start the transition into retirement and see how much you like it and what activities you enjoy.

This is a bad take because it implies retiring as soon as you have the funds to, rather than having extra fun money. For example, if OP got $1M / year as a raise it'd be a no brainier to keep working even if they have enough for retirement. It comes down to how much happiness money can buy vs. happiness lost by working.

@philn This does not seem to imply retiring as soon as you can afford at all. It just makes the point that if you have enough money to safely retire, the extra money from a raise makes very little difference in your overall budget. Anything you can afford with it, you could probably also afford without.

Job enjoyment can be affected (partly) by compensation.

If you're prepared to retire now, then ask them for a raise. If they decline to offer it then either retire now or continue working at your existing rate/salary. I don't see how your pending retirement factors into this at all and I don't see why you'd think this is a "tool" you could use to get what you want. You either want to retire or you want to continue working, regardless of the raise.

But the OP has told you the exact opposite of your last sentence. They are kind of done, but if the money was a little sweeter, they'd do it a little longer. You might not operate that way, but that's what the OP has said.

It matters because the amount of money I stand to make affects the balance of when it's not worth it anymore.

@TESch, but surely a raise in the typical range wouldn't make a difference to what it's "worth", when the alternative is retirement and zero earned income? I think the risk with this strategy is that your manager might not understand the logic of it.

If in the last one year OP earns 150 euro a month extra, that is sailing as opposed to hiking on their first holiday as a pensioner. Difference enough?

@Ivana, but they could earn that much extra (and probably quite a bit more) by just staying in work for another month. So if they wanted to sail rather than hike, there's no reason they couldn't afford that from existing funds already earned, or why the retirement date itself wouldn't already be set to accommodate the need to earn the extra (and paying the raise would actually precipitate retirement sooner rather than delay it).

At the risk of sounding a bit harsh in this post, you are too nice. As long as extorting is not illegal extort away. As you say most employers consider their employees completely disposable.
At the workplace the only person interest you should be concerned with is yourself. What happens to your manager after your leave is not your problem. Don't let him make his problems yours.
Think long and hard about what exactly you want and when you do, do what you consider to be in YOUR best interest. Don't let anything else influence your decision.

so you're basically wanting to tell them "Unless you give me a 50% raise today I quit tomorrow".
That's extortion, however you voice it. And were I that boss I'd fire you on the spot, have you escorted out of the building so you can't sabotage things before your access privileges are revoked.
You're clearly no longer motivated by wanting to work, only by raking in the cash. Doesn't make you an employee most companies want to have on their workforce.

Of course money is what motivates people to work, that's why employers need to pay it to have employees.

I'm sorry for firing him on the spot. There is an implicit threat of an employee leaving any time he/she asks for a raise that is denied. Making your intentions clear is no real cause for concern. He can ask and his employer can say no. It is a free country after all. No harm in asking.
